# WPF Frame doesn't get drawn out of Window

Tags: wpf, user-controls, controls, frame

I have two frames inside a grid like so:

```
<Grid x:Name="SlideGrid" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid, Converter={StaticResource DoubleConverter}}" Margin="0,28,0,0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ItemsControl Style="{DynamicResource StretchItem}" Grid.Column="0">
        <Frame x:Name="MP" Source="/ARC;component/MainPage.xaml" />
    </ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl Style="{DynamicResource StretchItem}" Grid.Column="1">
        <Frame x:Name="ARP" Source="/ARC;component/AddReferencePage.xaml"/>
    </ItemsControl>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

The grid takes up the whole window, so that the second items control is located out of window to the right. When I use a transition to slide the whole grid to the left, allowing use of the second user control, it just displays a white area. If I manually move the grid to be offset a little in the designer, so that a sliver of the second user control is visible, it still fails. Is there some setting for a frame to allow drawing of the control even is it is out of the window? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to draw outside of the Windows drawing context? In other words draw on the screen not your application?

Comment: Its okay. I just changed the way I was displaying the items to use a single ItemsControl.

Comment: can you please post your solution?